# Need to rewrite CNC file to shift absolute position

Tags: cnc

This question is really in two parts. To briefly introduce the issue, we have a requirement to take a CNC file (used with a Roland milling machine) that has been produced using a tool called ArtCam, and modify it to shift the absolute position of the pattern being cut.

The software produces, and the machine accepts, input files in the following form:

```
;;^IN;
!MC1;
!RC5000;
V50.0;
^PR;Z0,0,10500;
^PA;
V49.8;
Z0,0,1000;
V39.8;
Z0,0,100;
Z10,0,99;
Z1000,0,-13;
Z10,0,-124;
Z0,0,-125;
...thousands more Zx,y,z; instructions...
```

The first part to my question is, can anyone actually tell me what this file format is called? It's clearly not G-Code, and I haven't been able to find any reference or documentation for it anywhere.

The second part is, does anyone know how we might easily modify the absolute position of the pattern that these files cut. Obviously the Z lines are X,Y,Z position commands but I don't know if they're absolute or relative, and I don't know in what coordinate space/system they are. For all I know there might be a simple command we can add at the top that shifts the starting point, or we might need to rewrite all the Z lines, but without some information on the file format I'm at a dead end.

Thanks!

Comment: Never seen this kind of code before. Searching didn't help. If you have the machine on which you're running it, can't you tell what it is you're entering, or supposed to? Manuals?

Comment: I'm trying to get hold of some technical manuals, but so far no :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realise this is an old question and you maybe already have an answer (or have no need for one now) but it looks like it's RML-1, assuming my searches were correct.

I first found [this](http://www.digitalfabrication.net/tutorials/AADPL_CNC_Manual_2010.pdf) which showed very similar code to your example. It mentions ArtCAM and output for the MDX-540, a Roland machine.

Searching Roland's milling machines for information was a bit useless, but going through their [3D products for the MDX-540](http://www.rolanddg.com/product/3d/3d/mdx-540/spec.html) mentions that the control command sets is "RML-1 and NC codes".

Then searching for RML-1 gives a [result for a PDF manual](http://mlab.taik.fi/paja/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/RML1_Command_GuideENVer100.pdf).

Reading that PDF it looks like the single letter commands are "Mode 1", the ^ is used to select Mode2 and the 2 letter commands are Mode2 commands. !xx commands are common to both Mode1 and Mode2.

^PR sets the movement to relative mode.
^PA sets the movement to absolute mode.
Z moves.

Looking at your code sample it appears as if most positions are absolute and you'd need to re-write them all.

Comment: Thanks for that! By trial and error we'd pretty much worked out what the numbers meant but having the manual is still very handy.